# How to express this inverse complex series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

i know about geometric series in the normal form, but i've been incapable of find an expression for this series, any suggestions

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{0}(2e^{-jw})^{n}$$
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{0}(2e^{-jw})^{n} = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(2e^{-jw})^{-k} =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2^{-k}e^{jwk} =
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^{jw}}{2} \right)^{\!k}
$$

Comment: And now we can express this by the normal geometric series formula, $\frac{1}{1- \frac{e^{jw}}{2}} = \frac{2}{2 - e^{jw}}$.